# azure automation account pass azure context as paramters failed when using SP but identity works

Tags: azure, powershell

**what I have:**

I have a main runbook to generate azure context then pass to child runbook as parameters, there are two ways to generate the azure context in my main runbook.

1. connect azure using azure service principal.
2. connect azure using azure automation account managed identity

main.ps1:

```
Clear-AzContext -Force
Disable-AzContextAutosave

$devopsTenantId = ""
$clientId = ""
$clientSecret = ""
$securePassword = $clientSecret | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
#
try
{
    $credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientId, $securePassword
    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Write-Output "devops tenant single context --- with service principal"
    $AzureContext1 = (Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $devopsTenantId -Credential $credential).Context
    $runbook1AzContext = Set-AzContext -Subscription "DevOpsSub1" -DefaultProfile $AzureContext1
    $runbook1AzContext.GetType()
    $runbook1AzContext | Get-Member

    write-output "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Write-Output "devops tenant single context --- with managed identity"
    $AzureContext2 = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "").context
    $runbook2AzContext = Set-AzContext -Subscription "DevOpsSub1" -DefaultProfile $AzureContext2
    $runbook2AzContext.GetType()
    $runbook2AzContext | Get-Member
}
catch {
    Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
    throw $_.Exception
}

write-output "testing runbook1"
$runbook1Parameters = @{
    ResourceGroupName = "xxx"
    AzContext = $runbook1AzContext
}
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "xxx" `
    -Name "runbook1" `
    -ResourceGroupName "xxx" `
    -DefaultProfile $runbook1AzContext `
    -Parameters $runbook1Parameters

write-output "testing runbook2"
$runbook2Parameters = @{
    ResourceGroupName = "xxx"
    AzContext = $runbook2AzContext
}
Start-AzAutomationRunbook -AutomationAccountName "xxx" `
    -Name "runbook2" `
    -ResourceGroupName "xxx" `
    -DefaultProfile $runbook2AzContext `
    -Parameters $runbook2Parameters


Write-Output "check if sp produced context work in main runbook"
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "xxx" -DefaultProfile $runbook1AzContext
```

**result1:**

azure context generated in main runbook and works well for the both two contexts in main runbook

**test more:**

I have two child runbooks, they are identitcal and looks like below:

runbook1.ps1

```
Param(
     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
     [string]$ResourceGroupName,

     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
     [object]$AzContext
)

Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -DefaultProfile $AzContext
```

runbook2.ps1

```
Param(
     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
     [string]$ResourceGroupName,

     [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
     [object]$AzContext
)

Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -DefaultProfile $AzContext
```

**result2:**

when main runbook invoke runbook1 and runbook2, runbook2 works and return the resource group basic infos but runbook1 failed.

**failed infomations**

```
Get-AzResourceGroup : Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to set up your Azure credentials
```

**what I think:**
why azure context generated from SP and managed identity  works differently here?

Comment: Looks at the default profile in Main.  One is using $runbook1AzContext and the other $runbook2AzContext

Comment: @jdweng thanks man, which was I wanted. I split scripts into two login context.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `runbook1.ps1` did not receive the `$runbook1AzContext` object in the proper manner.

Before executing `Get-AzResourceGroup`, you can try explicitly supplying the context in `runbook1.ps1` using `Set-AzContext`

I tried in the below manner and it worked as shown.

```
Param(
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string] $ResourceGroupName,
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [object] $AzContext
)
#connect-Azaccount -Identity
set-Azcontext -context $Azcontext
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName
```

Or

```
#store runbook1context in $con parameter and pass it in the default profile flag
$con = set-Azcontext -context $Azcontext 
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $ResourceGroupName -DefaultProfile $con
```

*Output:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have followed your suggestions, but still not work in my side, which make me confused.
the same error "Your Azure credentials have not been set up or have expired, please run Connect-AzAccount to xxx".  I have also summit the support request to Azure, they told me not to pass azure context between runbooks. but I want to test "central login",  I really want to know how above works for you ? can you show your scripts ?

Comment: I've added script in the above answer and that is the script which worked for me. @wenbo

Comment: so you use the main.ps1 is what I provided in the Question, and the child.ps1 you pasted in ? how stranger it is,  I also use the child.ps1 copy from you. but failed.. @jahnavi

Comment: Try giving `clear-Azcontext` once and then give `set-Azcontext`. @wenbo